# How to delete a file after processing

Tags: bash, find, rm

I am using mp3splt to split all the .mp3 files under a directory, including subdirectories, into 30 minute slices.

```
find -name *.mp3 -print0 | xargs -0  mp3splt -t 30.00 -o @f_@m@s
```

What is the best way to delete the original file after the splitting is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and `chmod +x` the following script, `mp3splt_and_delete.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mp3splt -t 30.00 -o @f_@m@s "$@"
rm "$@"
```

Then you can run

```
find -name *.mp3 -print0 | xargs -0 /path/to/mp3splt_and_delete.sh
```

---

You could also try something like the following, but it'll create separate invocations of `mp3splt`:

```
find -name "*.mp3" -exec mp3split -t 30.00 -o @f_@m@s {} \; -a -delete
```

This requires `mp3split` to return a exit code of `0`, indicating success.

Comment: The first solution works just fine for me. I traversing the subdirectories is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp3
do
mp3splt -t 30.0.0 -o @f_@m@s "$file"
rm -f "$file"
done
```

Comment: @DanielBeck I have updated the answer. I think the added quotes do the trick.

Comment: I think so too, yes. Now you don't handle files in subdirectories, which are also returned by `find` without `-maxdepth`. Can't say if it's an issue for the user though.

Comment: @DanielBeck that's why I have added **quick fix**. We can add many more sophistications. And user himself have `find` without `maxdepth`.